# Animated double feature VHS tape, had a film about space maggots and the other about a robot that had lost control or something

Tags: story-identification, robots

As a child I watch this VHS tape with my dad a lot and I’m trying to find it again.

It was a double feature.

The first animated sci-fi cartoon was about alien space maggots that looked like big yellow sponges. I can’t really remember much more than that.

The second film was about a big red robot that had either lost control or was awakened and started destroying a city.

It’s all kind of hazy, but I can vividly picture the maggots and the robot in my head.

Comment: Thought the first one could be Bosco Adventure, but maggots from space are not yellow.